# NAT KVM Guest and Route All Guest Traffic to Host VPNC Connection

Tags: linux, iptables, port-forwarding, kvm-virtualization, vpn

I know this is ridiculous, but our admin said he would beat me to death if I tried bridging mode and refuses to enable port security on our Cisco switches.  Is there any way to get NAT traffic from `vnet0` to go the `tun0` adapter?  I cannot get traffic period, host or guess, without being connected to the VPN anyway, so I do not need to worry if it is connected.

My iptables dump (I assume this is what I will need to modify).  I assume I [might have to enable IPv4 forwarding, but wanted more guidance than this post gave me](https://serverfault.com/questions/167784/how-to-map-a-vpn-tun0-network-adapter-on-host-ubuntu-to-a-virtualbox-guest-wind).

> Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
>
> target     prot opt source               destination
>
> ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:domain
>
> ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:domain
>
> ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:bootps
>
> ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:bootps
>
> ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
>
> ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere
>
> ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
>
> ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
>
> ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW udp dpt:ipsec-nat-t
>
> REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
>
> Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
>
> target     prot opt source               destination
>
> ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             192.168.122.0/24    state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
>
> ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.122.0/24     anywhere
>
> ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
>
> REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
>
> REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
>
> REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
>
> Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
>
> target     prot opt source               destination

And my current adapter set. `eth0`, as easily assumed, is my main adapter, `tun0` from VPNC, and I assume vnet0 is for the NAT'ing, and the `virbr0` the bridging adapter I do and cannot use.

> eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
>
> ```
>       inet addr:10.2.25.252  Bcast:10.2.25.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
>
>       UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>
>       RX packets:6993223 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>
>       TX packets:6741080 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>
>       collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
>
>       RX bytes:5811139414 (5.4 GiB)  TX bytes:3373995210 (3.1 GiB)
>
>       Interrupt:21 Memory:fe9e0000-fea00000
> ```
>
> lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
>
> ```
>       inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
>
>       UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
>
>       RX packets:17912 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>
>       TX packets:17912 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>
>       collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
>
>       RX bytes:11251659 (10.7 MiB)  TX bytes:11251659 (10.7 MiB)
> ```
>
> tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
>
> ```
>       inet addr:10.2.7.181  P-t-P:10.2.7.181  Mask:255.255.255.255
>
>       UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1412  Metric:1
>
>       RX packets:203913 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>
>       TX packets:215693 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>
>       collisions:0 txqueuelen:500 
>
>       RX bytes:167581626 (159.8 MiB)  TX bytes:15541772 (14.8 MiB)
> ```
>
> virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
>
> ```
>       inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
>
>       UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>
>       RX packets:2054 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>
>       TX packets:243 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>
>       collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
>
>       RX bytes:253861 (247.9 KiB)  TX bytes:36640 (35.7 KiB)
> ```
>
> vnet0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
>
> ```
>       UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>
>       RX packets:2128 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>
>       TX packets:42948 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>
>       collisions:0 txqueuelen:500 
>
>       RX bytes:289277 (282.4 KiB)  TX bytes:2272356 (2.1 MiB)
> ```

Comment: Not sure what to do, but this was a really stupid question.  All you need to do in stock Fedora 14 with KVM enabled is [enable IPv4 forwarding](http://serverfault.com/questions/167784/how-to-map-a-vpn-tun0-network-adapter-on-host-ubuntu-to-a-virtualbox-guest-wind). The rest is handled for you.  Turns out I was pinging the wrong domain for testing right after I tried that ages ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embarrassingly enough, it was quite simple.  *ALL* I had to do was enable IPv4 forwarding.

`su -c 'echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward'`

Just hate seeing unanswered questions on the tubes.  No glory for the dense, especially those who ping a nonexistent domain in a test and presume that to mean the networking doesn't work.  :-\